# Why do e += 1 and e = e + 1 compile differently in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, global-variables, compiler-bug

I always assumed that `<var> += 1` and `<var> = <var> + 1` have the same semantics in JS.
Now, this CoffeeScript code compiles to different JavaScript when applied to the global variable `e`:

```
a: ->
  e = e + 1
b: ->
  e += 1
```

Note that `b` uses the global variable, whereas `a` defines a local variable:

```
({
  a: function() {
    var e;
    return e = e + 1;
  },
  b: function() {
    return e += 1;
  }
});
```

[Try it yourself.](http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20e%20%3D%20e%20%2B%201%0Ab%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20e%20%2B%3D%201%0A)
Is this a bug or is there a reason why this is so?

Comment: This is not a bug, coffeescript != javascript, there are subtle and disturbing semantic differences like this if you don't fully understand the way that coffeescript interprets the code. I would suggest reading over the coffeescript documentation for a full understanding of why this occurs.

Comment: http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope

Comment: Well, it may be intended, but it seems quite inconsistent. It certainly goes against Python's scoping rules, which CoffeeScript seems to be inspired by.

Comment: @Quintin: I did read the section you suggested, and I still don't get it. I know it's not JavaScript. Would you like to expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: I must admit I didn't know about this one - somehow looks nasty. however I would not write such code. Why would you change a global variable in a function of a object literal? Or more generic: why would you change a global in function or even more generic: why do you access a global variable at all?

Comment: @QuintinRobinson: I'd have to disagree, this is a bug or at least an inconsistency (which is often just a fancy word for *bug*). Compare `f = -> a += b`, `f = -> a ||= b`, `f = -> a &&= b`, ``f = -> a |= b`, ...

Comment: This is not a bug. It's even documented _explicitly_ [here](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope). At best you could call it a poor design decision. **Please read the documentation for the technologies that you use.**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Then perhaps you could point out where the different behavior of `f = -> a += b` and `f = -> a ||= b` is explicitly documented.

Comment: @Lightness, I *have* read the docs, as you would have known, had you read [my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258049/is-this-a-bug-in-coffeescript#comment18067884_13258049).

Comment: @muistooshort: That part is implicit. The section I linked to is about _declarations_, and `+=` has nothing to do with declarations. There's an argument to be made that `||=` should do the same thing, I'll grant you that; however, that particular operator is not documented _at all_ so you should not be relying on any particular behaviour other than what Javascript defines explicitly in the ECMA standard.

Comment: @DanAbramov: Yes, I saw that one. However there was no real evidence that you'd actually read it properly ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Then perhaps you could point out where it is implied or what makes `a += b` and `a = a + b` different things? I see inconsistent behavior and I'd be curious to know if you see any justification for it in the docs/spec.

Comment: @Lightness: There is a difference between reading and understanding. From reading your comment I understand you imply understanding by “reading”. It is precisely this difference that made me ask this question, in hope that someone would enlighten me by helping me understand what I have read.

Comment: @muistooshort: See my answer. `a = a + b` is a construct defined in CoffeeScript and given these "local" semantics. `a += b` is _not_ defined in CoffeeScript, takes the Javascript meaning and thus has the different semantics. It's not even terribly surprising -- in what language does `a += b` _declare anything new_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's the problem: sometimes CS recognizes that `a op= b` is screwy (`a ||= b`) and sometimes it doesn't (`a += b`). If I was in the UK I'd buy you a pint or two and we could fight over splitting hairs all night :)

Comment: @muistooshort: I do take Paypal if you wanna chip in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I would call this a bug or at least an undocumented edge case or ambiguity. I don't see anything in the docs that explicitly specifies when a new local variable is created in CoffeeScript so it boils down to the usual

> We do **X** when the current implementation does **X** and that happens because the current implementation does it that way.

sort of thing.

The condition that seems to trigger the creation of a new variable is assignment: it looks like CoffeeScript decides to create a new variable when you try to give it a value. So this:

```
a = ->
  e = e + 1
```

becomes

```
var a;
a = function() {
  var e;
  return e = e + 1;
};
```

with a local `e` variable because you are explicitly assigning `e` a value. If you simply refer to `e` in an expression:

```
b = ->
  e += 1
```

then CoffeeScript won't create a new variable because it doesn't recognize that there's an assignment to `e` in there. CS recognizes an expression but isn't smart enough to see `e +=1` as equivalent to `e = e + 1`.

Interestingly enough, CS does recognize a problem when you use an `op=` form that is part of CoffeeScript but not JavaScript; for example:

```
c = ->
  e ||= 11
```

yields an error that:

> the variable "e" can't be assigned with ||= because it has not been defined

I think making a similar complaint about `e += 1` would be sensible and consistent. Or all `a op= b` expressions should expand to `a = a op b` and be treated equally.

---

If we look at the CoffeeScript source, we can see what's going on. If you poke around a bit you'll find that all the `op=` constructs end up going through [`Assign#compileNode`](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/src/nodes.coffee#L1020):

```
compileNode: (o) ->
  if isValue = @variable instanceof Value
    return @compilePatternMatch o if @variable.isArray() or @variable.isObject()
    return @compileSplice       o if @variable.isSplice()
    return @compileConditional  o if @context in ['||=', '&&=', '?=']
  #...
```

so there is special handling for the CoffeeScript-specific `op=` conditional constructs as expected. A quick review suggests that `a op= b` for non-conditional `op` (i.e. `op`s other than `||`, `&&`, and `?`) pass straight on through to the JavaScript. So what's going on with `compileCondtional`? Well, as expected, [it checks that you're not using undeclared variables](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/master/src/nodes.coffee#L1125):

```
compileConditional: (o) ->
  [left, right] = @variable.cacheReference o
  # Disallow conditional assignment of undefined variables.
  if not left.properties.length and left.base instanceof Literal and 
         left.base.value != "this" and not o.scope.check left.base.value
    throw new Error "the variable \"#{left.base.value}\" can't be assigned with #{@context} because it has not been defined."
  #...
```

There's the error message that we see from `-> a ||= 11` and a comment noting that you're not allowed to `a ||= b` when `a` isn't defined somewhere.

Comment: @Dan: Hopefully [Trevor Burnham](http://stackoverflow.com/users/66226/trevor-burnham) will have something to say about this. He did write the book after all.

Answer (score 3):

This can be pieced together from the documentation:

- `=`: Assignment in [Lexical scope](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope)

  > The CoffeeScript compiler takes care to make sure that all of your variables are properly declared within lexical scope — you never need to write `var` yourself.
  >
  > `inner` within the function, on the other hand, should not be able to change the value of the external variable of the same name, and therefore **has a declaration of its own**.

  The example given in this section is precisely the same as your case.
- `+=` and `||=`

  This is not a declaration, so the above does not apply. In its absence, `+=` takes on its usual meaning, as does `||=`.

  In fact, since these are not redefined by CoffeeScript, they take their meaning from ECMA-262 — the underlying target language — which yields the results you've observed.

  Unfortunately, this "fall-through" doesn't seem to be explicitly documented.

Comment: Hi, thanks for coming by. Isn't `e += 1` an [assignment expression](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13) (`LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression`) as per ECMA-262?

Comment: @DanAbramov: Yes. But assignment and declaration are different things. And, certainly, `a += b` when a `a` is already in scope will _never_ declare a new `a` in Javascript. Your confusion stems from the fact that CoffeeScript "overloads" the meaning of `=` but not any of the other `=` operators. It's not even that surprising really - it could be considered to make sense that `a = a + b` does what it does here, but I'd _never_ expect `a += b` to do it.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it now. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @DanAbramov: Pas de probleme

Comment: Except that there is no `||=` in JavaScript so `||=` *is* defined by CoffeeScript. So we're left with holes in the spec and whether or not *holes* are *bugs*.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that once you make declarations implicit, you open up a few unpleasant edges case as to when something is actually declared. If declarations are explicit then there is no problem, if they're implicit then you open yourself up to ambiguity and you need to explicitly enumerate exactly what "implied declaration" means. There are problems with working in a language that hasn't gone through the slow and nasty formal committee specification process (and different problems when a language does go through that process).

Comment: @muistooshort: Oh, I never said this was a _good_ design decision.

Comment: Hmm about `||=` -- that's not in the question. You were the first to bring it up! Cheater...

Answer (score 2):

This issue has very recently [been discussed on CoffeeScript's Github Issues](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2605). It seems the current behaviour of the compiler was was agreed upon, or at least discussed, on [this previous issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1122).

Basically, in JavaScript the expressions `e = e + 1` and `e += 1` are always equivalent, as they never introduce a new variable: they will always add `1` to the (local or global) `e` variable, or they will fail if `typeof e === 'undefined'`. Now, the expression `var e = e + 1` is valid in JavaScript and will declare the `e` variable and assign it to the value of adding `undefined` and `1` (`NaN`, obviously =P), while `var e += 1` is syntactically invalid.

In CoffeeScript, `e = e + 1` can be a variable declaration in case `e` was not declared before, or just an assignment statement if `e` is defined in the current scope, while `e += 1` never introduces a new variable (a somewhat reasonable behaviour, as it doesn't make sense to increment a previously undeclared variable).

This is the current behaviour as i understand it. I think it's kind of unfortunate that `e = e + 1` and `e += 1` can mean different things, but i understand that it's a consequence of the combination of implicit variable declarations and JavaScript's scoping rules (this [this comment](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2605#issuecomment-10095685) for a, probably quite biased, explanation).

Comment: And we're still left with the inconsistent `||=` behavior. `Assign.prototype.compileNode` has specific checks for an undeclared `a` in `a ||= b` while `a += b` gets pass straight through to the JavaScript; presumably this is because `||=` is CS but not JS while `+=` is CS and JS. Thanks for digging through the Github issues though.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, i totally agree. I'd really appreciate if you could give some technical insights (like the ones in your answer) or your opinion in [this discussion](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2605) that is currently being held on.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2605#issuecomment-10137674) work for you? I think your proposal is the only sensible thing to do: treat all `op=` the same and get on with it :)

Comment: Of course it does! Thanks. About the proposal, i haven't really thought about it very thoroughly, so there probably are some corner cases that could render it invalid. And it's also a backward-incompatible change. No matter if it's well intended, if it breaks lots of working code, then the cure might be worse than the disease =P

Comment: I don't see how complaining consistently could break anything that isn't broken already, you'd just know that it is broken sooner. And if someone is depending on broken behavior then, well, they'll get exactly what they deserve. Maybe I'm just a cranky old man yelling at those damn kids to get off my lawn but I don't have much sympathy for sloppiness.